# Spring Integration Feed Inbound Channel Adapter duplicate entries

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to consume RSS feeds using its inbound channel adapter and writing the feeds to a database table.

To prevent duplicate entries when the process is stopped/started, I have enabled the PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore. As a secondary measure, on the database table, I also have a unique constraint across the feed id/feed entry link columns.

This seems to be working fine but I have noticed on some restarts (not all the time) that I am getting some DB exception errors where it is trying to insert the same RSS feed item again.

Under what conditions would I being getting these duplicate errors and is there anyway I can get round them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` only persists its state on a normal application shutdown (when the bean is `destroy()`ed by the application context).

However, it implements `Flushable` so you can either call `flush()` on it in your flow after persisting.

You could use [transaction synchronization](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization) to flush the store after the db transaction commits with the after commit expression `@metadataStore.flush()`.

Or, you could use a more robust persistent store, such as Redis, which persists on each update.

Comment: Thanks Gary. The application is shutting down normally so I assume the state is getting persisted but I agree that I need to start looking to use Redis. I had a look at the PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore documentation and it looks like its using the latest published date in the metadatastore. I suspect what's happening is for some feeds, the published date is being updated hence why it appears again. If this is the case, is it easy to catch this exception and do an update of the item using DSL?

Comment: You can add an errorChannel to the poller and do the update on the error flow (the payload of the `ErrorMessage` is a `MessagingException` with properties `failedMessage` and `cause`). Alternatively, you can add an [`ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice) to the jdbc adapter's endpoint `adviceChain`.

Comment: I wish we fix https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-1810 one day... And this use-case would be met as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to workaround it by modifying the [MYSQL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in my JDBCmessageHandler to handle the duplicate record and just do an update of the fields.